# How to fix the issue of "ImportError: No module named twilio.rest"?

Tags: python, twilio

When I run the code, it displays the error

```
"No module named twilio.rest.
```

I had tried to uninstall and install few time with pip.

```
from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
                       to="",
                       from_="",
                       body="" )

print(message.sid)

ImportError: No module named twilio.rest
```

Comment: you need to import the module

Comment: did you save it in file `twilio.py`? If yes then now it tries to import from your file, not from expected modul, and it can't find this element in your file.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? You can try installing `pip3 install twilio`

Comment: It is 2.7 python. What you mean save it in twilio.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have the correct interpreter set for your project and that interpreter have the **twilio** library install. As sometimes we have multiple interpreter in our IDE.

Comment: Hi, how to check my project is using which interpreter. Currently the twilio file is in lib something

Comment: I think I use the wrong interpreter. Currently issue solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first, you check your **python-pip** version which is **2 or 3**
after you install Twilio
if you use **python3** and install **Twilio** using **pip2** then this issue generate

Comment: Hi, i am using Python 2.7. The command i use for download Twilio is pip install twilio